# When should I email again about status of position I applied for?

Tags: interviewing, email, follow-up

I had the second interview for a software developer position last Wednesday, and I think it went well; one of the managers who was not involved in the hiring decision even told me at the end that he hopes they decide to hire me.

The hiring manager said they would make a decision that day, relay the decision to HR, and I should hear back in a couple days. It has been 3 business days and I have heard nothing.

I emailed the hiring manager a few days ago to say thank you and that I looked forward to hearing from him, but he did not reply. I know Thanksgiving is coming, but would it be appropriate to email again before the holiday? I don't want to seem like I lost interest in the job.

Comment: "A couple of days" is often more than 3 business days...

Answer (score 1):

> I know Thanksgiving is coming, but would it be appropriate to email again before the holiday?

Seems that it has been only 3 days, you should probably wait *at least* a week or so before considering writing a reply. Thus, you could try and wait after Thanksgiving to hear back from them before contacting them.

Besides, you say that it is the Second Round of interviews, which suggests they do like your profile enough to continue the process. Also, you say you did good on the interview, so I would not worry much about this.

Just give them some time, as every company has a specific process in which they consider their candidates.